# Getting NaN & aN return value from website instead of remaining time

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I made a countdown timer with the following code:

```js
function getTimeRemaining (endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

console.log(getTimeRemaining("may 17 2020 12:00:00"));
```

Website gives: NaN days, aN hours, aN minutes and aN seconds as response, what is the problem?
I'm using javascript

Comment: `Date.parse(endtime)` fails

Comment: Why does it fail

Comment: because endtime does not comply to the input formats Date.parse accepts.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your values by:
   getTimeRemaining(1).days
getTimeRemaining(1).total
getTimeRemaining(1).hours
getTimeRemaining(1).minutes
getTimeRemaining(1).seconds

Answer (score 0):

change the code to:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
            var t = new Date(endtime) - new Date();
            var seconds = t.getSeconds()
            var minutes = t.getMinutes();
            var hours = t.getHours();
            var days = t.getDay();
            return {
                'total': t,
                'days': days,
                'hours': hours,
                'minutes': minutes,
                'seconds': seconds
            };
        }
```

Comment: @M.Ince can u share the `endtime` argument which u r passing?

Comment: It has the type DateTime, comes from the model

Comment: can u share the dateTime string which u r getting from model

Comment: 18-5-2020 15:00:00

Comment: this is invalid date format. convert it to `may 17 2020 12:00:00` in this format

Comment: @RohitSingh bad suggestion. always use ISO 8601 if you desire to use a string. you are literally ignoring timezones.